# Call to undefined function mysqli_init()

Tags: php, mysqli

An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined function mysqli_init()

Filename: /home/sourcecars/public_html/carsonbarlcon.com/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 135

Backtrace:

File: /home/sourcecars/public_html/carsonbarlcon.com/application/hooks/EloquentHook.php
Line: 31
Function: database

File: /home/sourcecars/public_html/carsonbarlcon.com/application/hooks/EloquentHook.php
Line: 46
Function: loadDatabase

File: /home/sourcecars/public_html/carsonbarlcon.com/index.php
Line: 316
Function: require_once

Install mysqli php extension

Answer (score 0):

1. please check `php-mysqli` is installed?
2. check `php.ini` and make sure the extension is loaded.
   `extension=php_mysqli.dll`
3. if it's a php framework make sure in the framework `config.php` file what driver you are using.